# Error cs0029 on form load

Tags: c#, user-interface

I made a few forms and everything was working correctly
now I created a new form and i am getting this error

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string'
>   to'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

and it shows red line on this one

```
this.Name = "Form8";
```

to fix this error i just add // before this line but it is removed automatically when i try to run the project again
what should i do?

Comment: Have you _ever_ read your error message? It is quite clear. Looks like your `Name` is a `Label`. Maybe you want to do `this.Name.Text = "Form8";` instead?

Comment: try using this.Name.Text = "Form8"